# software for one class classification with a Bayesian Network

Tags: bayesian-network, anomaly-detection, software, one-class

I'm looking for a software package that would allow to do a one class classification with a Bayesian Network (anomaly detection).

I was planning to use bnlearn but so far I'm unable to find out if the library supports it.

Basically all I need is to get a measure of probability of an unseen data to belong to the distribution represented by the Bayesian Network.

All libraries I found so far only allow to query for some unknown variable given partial evidence.

Does someone know about a library that would support such a query? (The ideal case would be one that also supports Laplace smoothing)

Answer (score 1):

So far this is the best I could find on the topic. It's preferably used together with bnlearn and allows log-likelihood computation without rules:
https://github.com/nezezime/bnAnomaly

Comment: Did you manage to use this library on same real sample data?

Comment: I integrated it for a test run, but I couldn't get it to run straight away and I didn't invest more time in it